# generic attribute in java with multiple fields

Tags: java, spring, generics

i have a question. do you know how can i use the same field with différent generic attribut implementation.

I have an interface for modelMapper that i am using to generalise the Type of objects that will be mapped

```
public interface IMapper<S, D> {

D map(S src, Class destination);
}
```

I also have this implementation of this interface :

```
@Component
public class ModelMapperImpl<S,D> implements IMapper<S,D> {

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public D map(S src, Class destination) {
        return (D) mapper.map(src, destination);
    }
}
```

The problem is this, i need to have for each mapping a field in my class which is not a good practice i think and i am searching if there is a way to have only one generic field for all my type of mappings

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private IMapper<AddressDTO, Address> mapperAddress;

    private  IMapper<UsersDTO, Users> mapperUser;  // i want to have only one IMapper field
```

is there is a way to do That ? thank you guys for your help.

Comment: Your IMapper and ModelMapperImpl should in fact not be generic, only the `map` method.

Comment: Like `public interface IMapper{ <S,D> D map (S src, Class destination); }` , not sure if we can elimiate the need for the Class param. I based my example on [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you are trying to make it easy to change the mapping library(moving from ModelMapper to something else, if it's needed). Then you can make the method generic, not the class.

```
public interface IMapper {
  
  <S, D> D map(S src, Class<D> destination);
}
```

Impl:

```
@Component
public class ModelMapperImpl implements IMapper {

  @Autowired
  private ModelMapper mapper;

  @Override
  public <S, D> D map(S src, Class<D> destinationClass) {
    return mapper.map(src, destinationClass);
  }
}
```

Now you need only one `IMapper` in your service.

```
@Service
public class UserService {

  @Autowired
  private IMapper mapper;
}
```

Comment: thank u for ur response, yes exactly i'm trying to put the O in the solid principal by doing this. your solution i already did it but sonarQube will not accept it because in the line below he will throw a warning saying that the interface must have generic attribut   private IMapper<?,?> mapper;

Comment: @Abdelghafour Check the interface again, you have to remove the generic params from it and move them to the method only.